# Алгоритм локализации точки в невыпуклой триангуляции

Tags: алгоритм, графы

При редактировании триангуляции она может потерять выпуклость или возыметь в себе дыру (но не может полностью разделиться на 2 и более островов). Встала необходимость локализации очень большого количества точек в заданных условиях, а реализованный алгоритм поиска (итерационный с динамическим массивом), ни в какую не хочет работать хотя бы быстрее перебора всех треугольников. Может кто-нибудь подсказать алгоритм?

Comment: Ммм... А в выпуклой триангуляции получается быстро искать? Если [алгоритм за логарифм](https://studfile.net/preview/899050/page:6/) или другой быстрый реализован, то можно охватывающий треугольник  сделать, триангулировав и новую область.  По триангуляциям  с дырками у Скворцова были работы, может, что-то полезное найдёте.

Comment: В выпуклой ищется довольно бодро примерно за O(n), но от вписывания пришлось отказаться т.к. триангуляция спокойно может быть вытянутой и насчитывать несколько миллионов точек, а алгоритм проверки на видимость у меня не самый производительный да и рассчитан именно на выпуклую, его бы тоже хорошо переписать, но тут уж дело только в лени. А где у Скворцова было про триангуляцию с дырками, это какая-то отдельная статья? Я просто у него только книжные работы знаю.

Comment: Видимо, это "Алгоритмы построения триангуляции с ограничениями" мне так запомнились. Не уверен, что это вам подойдёт. Возможно, @Stanislav Volodarskiy сюда заглянет и что-то подскажет

Comment: Там про то как не дать триангуляции перебросить конкретные, заранее заданные рёбра. В любом случае спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придумал +- решение, так что оставлю тут описание, на случай если когда-нибудь, кто-нибудь столкнётся с подобным:

1. Прежде всего определяется находится ли точка внутри внешнего контура триангуляции.
2. С помощью примерного поиска находим треугольник неподалёку от нужной точки.
3. Создаём отрезок между некой точкой внутри треугольника и искомой точкой, а лучше несколько для хоть какой-то точности при превышении пределов значимых цифр double. (Далее отрезок называется А).
4. Проверяем пересечение между А и внешним контуром триангуляции.
5. При наличии оного находим ребро с которым произошло **последнее** пересечение .
6. Продолжаем поиск обычным итерационным алгоритмом из треугольника которому принадлежит ребро из пункта 5.

Дополнение:

1. Данный алгоритм работает только если точно известно что точка лежит внутри триангуляции.
2. Опыты в голове и наяву показали что после пункта 5 при определенном контуре поиск всё равно может наткнуться на внешний контур. Это правится повторением алгоритма.
3. Изначально думал что придётся переделывать контур из простого списка с отрезками в полноценный объект-полилинию, оказалось что это только усложнит задачу. Так что при таком поиске желательно отображать внешний контур именно как список отрезков.

P.S. Ничего лучше за полгода что у меня висит эта проблема я не придумал и не нашёл. Спасибо за ответы.